# Failed to compare result of converting rgb to nv12

Tags: opencl

I am practing OpenCL by converting rgb to NV12
I have received an comparison failure message as below:

> "[Error] failed to compare Y plane at x(0) y(1) output_cpu(18) output_cl(16)"

I am using a simple 16x16 RGB buffer with `R=1, G=2, B=3`, layout as below:

```
123 123 123 123 123 ....
123 123 123.............
```

Can anybody help explain the reason for this comparison error?

Here is my test code of CPU conversion

```
int rgb, r, g, b, y, u, v;
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        // src is int rgb buffer
        rgb = src[i * width + j];
        r = rgb & 0xFF;
        g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        b = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        y = ((66 * r + 129 * g + 25 * b + 128) >> 8) + 16; y = y > 255 ? 255 : (y < 0 ? 0 : y);
        u = ((-38 * r - 74 * g + 112 * b + 128) >> 8) + 128; u = u > 255 ? 255 : (u < 0 ? 0 : u);
        v = ((112 * r - 94 * g - 18 * b + 128) >> 8) + 128; v = v > 255 ? 255 : (v < 0 ? 0 : v);
        // dst is unsigned char YUV buffer
        dst[i * width + j] = (unsigned char)y;
    }
}
```

Here is conversion of CL version

```
__kernel void rgb_2_nv12(__global unsigned int* src, __global char* dst, uint w, uint h)
{
    int x = get_global_id(0);
     y = get_global_id(1);
    int RGB, R, G, B, Y, U, V;
    unsigned int pos;

    pos = y * w + x;
    half_w = w >> 1;
    // src is same int rgb buffer
    RGB = src[y * w + x];
    R = RGB & 0xff;
    G = (RGB >> 8) & 0xff;
    B = (RGB >> 16) & 0xff;

    Y = ((66 * R + 129 * G + 25 * B + 128) >> 8) + 16;
    Y = Y > 255 ? 255 : (Y < 0 ? 0 : Y);
    U = ((-38 * R - 74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
    U = U > 255 ? 255 : (U < 0 ? 0 : U);
    V = ((112 * R - 94 * G - 18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
    V = V > 255 ? 255 : (V < 0 ? 0 : V);  
    // dst is unsigned char YUV buffer          
    dst[pos] = (unsigned char)Y;
```

Here is my CL setting:

```
cl_mem cl_buf_src = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, rgb_size, input_int, &err); // rgb_size = 16x16, unsigned it input_int[rgb_size] 
cl_mem cl_buf_dst = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, yuv_size, output_cl, &err); // yuv_size = 1.5 * rgb_size, unsigned char output_cl[yuv_size]
clSetKernelArg(kernel_rgb_2_nv12, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&cl_buf_src); // int 
clSetKernelArg(kernel_rgb_2_nv12, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&cl_buf_dst);
clSetKernelArg(kernel_rgb_2_nv12, 2, sizeof(cl_uint), &w); // 16
clSetKernelArg(kernel_rgb_2_nv12, 3, sizeof(cl_uint), &h); // 16

size_t globalWorkSize[2] = { w, h };
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel_rgb_2_nv12, 2, NULL, globalWorkSize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem that the parameter size of clCreateBuffer() is in byte.
So, here I should use rgb_size * 4, not rgb_size.